# Posting a topic related to notes

Tags: support, scope

I wanted to check if it is OK to post a question asking for material to study/explanation, as I tried to research about a particular topic and wasn't clear on the implementation.

Comment: Asking for material: no. Explanation: perhaps, but you'd need to demonstrate that you've done the research and specifically what you're having problems with.

Answer (score 6):

Asking for material to study is off-topic. Asking for an explanation on a certain topic *may* be on-topic. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic:

> **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the
>   categories listed above:**
>
> 4. Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software
>      library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack
>      Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>      Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve
>      it.